# How to provide flyway password to gradle task command line argument?

Tags: gradle, flyway

I was trying to setup gradle task to Migrate my postgreSQL(any DB) using flyway.
Below is one way of doing it, but I don't want to write password in gradle build file.

```
flyway {
        url  = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/DB_NAME'
        user = 'username'
        password = '********'
}
```

And run task,

```
./gradlew flywayMigrate -i
```

Is it possible to provide this as command line argument, something like below?

```
./gradlew flywayMigrate -i -password ********
```

I checked https://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/migrate#configuration, https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/gradle which did not help much.
NOTE : This question might look similar to How to provide argument to gradle build task so I tried below which didn't work either. Thanks in advance.

```
./gradlew flywayMigrate -i -Ppassword ********
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties can be passed in with a `flyway.` prefix:

```
./gradlew flywayMigrate -i -Pflyway.password=********
```

See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/#gradle-properties

Comment: This works for me, the above solution is missing the "=" after the property name. I'm also using Gradle v7.4.2: 

`./gradlew flywayMigrate -i -Pflyway.password=********`